# .Any suggestions on the things to be considered to boot Linux Kernel for RISCV?

Tags: fpga, riscv

We are developing RISC-V soft-processor in Verilog.So far we have implemented 12 stage pipeline, Data and Instruction cache and M-extension.We are going to add F extension susequently.What are the feature we have to improve for boot Linux Kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Linux distributions all currently target RV64GC, so if you want to be able to run software out of the box you'll want to support RV64GC.  It's possible to run Linux on other systems, with various caveats:

- Systems without the A extension aren't currently supported, but adding support for single-hart systems without the A extension wouldn't be too much work.  This would require recompiling all of userspace.
- Systems without the M and C extensions aren't currently supported, but it should be possible to just recompile userspace and get a working system.
- Systems without the F and D extensions are currently supported, but Linux distributions aren't targeting these as their first target.  We test these regularly, but not to the extent that porting a full Linux distribution would so you might find bugs.
- RV32I-based Linux systems are currently known to be broken, but there is nothing fundamentally wrong with them.  Expect to run into a pile of bugs if you try to run Linux on an RV32I-based system today, but we'll eventually fix this.